# how to get contact history of customers in aws connect. i want to add contact history to my ui of web applications

Tags: amazon-web-services

https://gist.github.com/alonch/2887d941689f8dbd560614c8667e6300
i used this format like adding lambda to send details to dynamodb. but it is not worked.
https://gist.github.com/alonch/2887d941689f8dbd560614c8667e6300
i used this format like adding lambda to send details to dynamodb. but it is not worked.
https://gist.github.com/alonch/2887d941689f8dbd560614c8667e6300
i used this format like adding lambda to send details to dynamodb. but it is not worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.